# Local method is not updating the instance variables of my mocked class

Tags: java, testng, mockito

I am new to mockito. Spent more than a day now, trying to figure out how this works. This is my last resort.

I have a class as follows:

```
class Check{
  //Map<String, Long> map1 = new HashMap<String, Long>();
  //Map<String, Long> map2 = new HashMap<String, Long>();

boolean myLocalMethod(String key, Map<String, Long> map1){
  if(map1.get(key) == null){
    map1.put("name", (long)10);
    return false;
  }
  else if(map1.get(key) == 10)
          return true;
       else
          return false;
}
```

I have a test class as follows:

```
class TestCheck(){
 Check mockTest = mock(Check.class);

 @Test // using testng. That's what I like
 public void testMyLocalMethod(){
   Map<String, Long> map1 = new HashMap<String, Long>();
   Assert.assertFalse(mockTest.myLocalMethod("name", map1));
   map1.put("name", (long)10);
   Assert.assertTrue(mockTest.myLocalMethod("name", map1)); // fails
```

It will be great if someone can give me some guidance here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mockito isn't using your implementation, just your interface. You shouldn't expect it to update any variables. If you actually want to use your implementation of `Check`, just instantiate it normally.

Comment: Oh okay. So, by running the test, the map1.put("name", 10) will not get updated if I use mock(Check.class)?

Comment: Correct. See my answer below for some example code of how you can think about the way the mock is implemented.

Comment: The idea of mocking is that you don't mock the class you're trying to test - you mock OTHER classes that it interacts with.  This lets you isolate the functionality of your class from functionality that other classes may provide, so that you can better focus your test.

Comment: I agree to that Dave. However, in this case, it has some configuration overhead which I don't want to add in my tests. That is why I am trying to use this as a mock class. I know this is not a perfect way of doing it, but I still want to have unit tests against this class without going through the configuration overhead that this class originally needs.

Comment: But if you don't do the required configuration, are you really testing that objects of that class behave the way they ought to?

Comment: Yeah, the original configuration file, is just some input properties that is being read from a properties file and all. I am not interested in all of that while running the tests. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ask Mockito to mock a class, it overrides your existing implementation. Internally, it defines a new class, which at a basic level would look something like this, if you did it explicitly and don't add any additional behaviour using `when` or similar:

```
class MockCheck extends Check {
  @Override
  void myLocalMethod(String key) {}
}
```

i.e. calling `myLocalMethod` doesn't actually invoke the parent class' version of `myLocalMethod`.

If you want to use your implementation of `Check`, just instantiate it like a regular object:

```
Check mockTest = new Check();
```

Comment: Andy, thanks a lot for the help so far! I am understanding mockito better now. I don't want to use the original class as it has some configuration overhead and that is why I am trying to mock it. I have changed the code and do you know why the Assert.assertTrue fails with the change I have made?

Comment: I am surprised it even compiles. `myLocalMethod` is of type `void`, so you can't use it as a parameter to another method call.

Comment: `map1.put("name", 10);` won't compile either. Should be `10L`.

Comment: Made changes. If the datatype was not a problem, does it look like it is supposed to work?

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks a lot! I think my original question has been answered.

Comment: Andy, just wanted to let you know that using static on some of those methods helped me to get the expected results too. Instead of invoking Check objCheck = new Check(); I am now invoking the methods that need to make changes in a static context.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, a mock object will not use your actual implementation. But, you can use a `Spy` object to verify behaviors, while using your actual implementation, see [Spying on real objects](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13)